# Django forms. Save data but do not validate until submission

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new to Django and have been doing lots of reading so perhaps this is a noob question.

We have applications that involve many forms that users fill out along the way.  One user might fill out the budget page and another user might fill out the project description page.  Along the way any data they input ***will be SAVED but NOT validated.***

On the review page only data is shown and no input boxes / forms.  At the bottom is a submit button.  When the user submits the application I then want validation to be performed on all the parts / pages / forms of the application.  If there are validation errors then the application can not be submitted.

My model fields are mostly marked as blank=True or null=True depending on the field type.  Some fields are required but most I leave blank or null to allow the users to input data along the way.

Any advice on best practices or do not repeat yourself is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of learning, playing and reading I think I have figured a few things and will share them here.  I do not know if this is right, however it is progress for me.

So first comes the models.  Everything needs to accept blank or null depending on the field type.  This will allow the end user to input data as they get it:

```
class exampleModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=25)
    field_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    .........
```

Then we create our model form:

```
from your.models import exampleModel
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Row, Column

class exampleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = exampleModel
        fields = ('field_1','field_2')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # DID WE GET A VALIDATE ARGUMENT?
        self.validate = kwargs.pop('validate', False)
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # SEE IF WE HAVE TO VALIDATE
        for field in self.fields:
            if self.validate:
                self.fields[field].required = True
            else:
                self.fields[field].required = False

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('field_1', css_class='col-lg-4 col-md-4'),
                Column('field_2', css_class='col-lg-4 col-md-4')
            )
        )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ExampleForm, self).clean()

        field_1 = cleaned_data.get('field1')
        field_2 = cleaned_data.get('field2')

        if self.validate and field_2 != field_2:
            self.add_error('field_1', 'Field 1 does not match field2')

        return cleaned_data
```

Here is the important part.  I've learned a lot about forms and binding.  As I mentioned I needed users to be able to fill out forms and not validate the data till the very end.  This is my solution which helped me.  I could not find a way to **bind** a form to the model data, so I created a function in my lib called bind_queryset_to_form which looks like this:

```
def bind_queryset_to_form(qs, form):
    form_data = {}
    my_form = form()
    for field in my_form.fields:
        form_data[field] = getattr(qs, field, None)
    my_form = form(data=form_data, validate=True)
    return my_form
```

The view:

```
from your.models import exampleModel
from your.form import exampleForm
from your.lib.bind_queryset_to_form import bind_queryset_to_form

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def your_view(request, pk):
    query_set = get_object_or_404(exampleModel, id=pk)
    context = dict()
    context['query_set'] = query_set

    # SAVE THE FORM (POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = exampleForm(request.POST, instance=query_set)
        form.save()
        context['form'] = form

    # GET THE DATA.
    if request.method == 'GET':
       if request.session.get('validate_data'):
           # BIND AND VALIDATE
           context['form'] = bind_queryset_to_form(query_set, exampleForm)
       else:
           # NO BIND, NO VALIDATE
           context['form'] = exampleForm(instance=query_set)

    return render(request, 'dir/your.html', context)
```

The template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div id="div_some_tab">
    <form id="form_some_tab" action="{% url 'xx:xx' query_set.id %}" method="post">
        {% crispy form form.helper %}
    </form>
</div>
```

What does all the above allow?

I have many views with many data inputs.  The user can visit each view and add data as they have it.  On the review page I set the flag / session "validate_data".  This causes the app to start validating all the fields.  Any errors will all be displayed on the review page.  When the user goes to correct the errors for the given view the **bind_queryset_to_form(query_set, exampleForm)** is called binding the form with data from the queryset and highlighting any errors.

I cut out a lot of the exceptions and permission to keep this as transparent as possible (the goat would hate that).  Hope this idea might help someone else or someone else might improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app in django called [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/). Using it you can split form submission process for multiple steps.

Comment: Thanks!  I see that is was removed from django 1.8  but was separated into a standalone package.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-formtools